# Distinguishing between the blog title and the post title when creating a custom theme for Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

Long time lurker, first time asker.

I am currently writing a custom theme for Tumblr blogs to embed a widget after every post, regardless of their type. This widget requires the post's title, and if there is none, then it takes the blog's title.

According to [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#basic_variables), {Title} refers to the blog title. However, if we have a Text post or a Chat post, {Title} refers to the post title.

Here is my code:

```
var title;
if ('{PostType}' === 'text' || '{PostType}' === 'chat') 
    title = '{Title}';
else if ('{PostType}' === 'photo' || '{PostType}' === 'photoset' || '{PostType}' === 'audio' || '{PostType}' === 'video')
    title = '{PlaintextCaption}';
else if ('{PostType}' === 'quote')
    title = '{PlaintextQuote}';
else if ('{PostType}' === 'link')
    title = '{PlaintextName}';
else if ('{PostType}' === 'answer')
    title = '{PlaintextQuestion}';

if (title === '')
    title = '{Title}';
```

If I have a Photo post with no caption for example, then title will be correctly set to the blog title. But if I have a Text post with no title, then title will be set to [empty string] instead of the blog title.

So my question is: how can I get the blog title when I am inside of a Text or Chat post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is set the blog title as a variable before you enter into your `{block:Posts}`. So in your `<head>`, you can do this:

```
var blogTitle = '{Title}';
```

Then modify your code like this:

```
var title;
if ('{PostType}' === 'text' || '{PostType}' === 'chat') 
    title = blogTitle;
else if ('{PostType}' === 'photo' || '{PostType}' === 'photoset' || '{PostType}' === 'audio' || '{PostType}' === 'video')
    title = '{PlaintextCaption}';
else if ('{PostType}' === 'quote')
    title = '{PlaintextQuote}';
else if ('{PostType}' === 'link')
    title = '{PlaintextName}';
else if ('{PostType}' === 'answer')
    title = '{PlaintextQuestion}';

if (title === '')
    title = '{Title}';
```

Also, be careful, as `{PostType}` will never `== 'photoset'`. Photoset post types always come out as 'photo'. What I usually do to counter that when making class names is this:

```
class="type-{PostType}{block:Photoset}set{/block:Photoset}
```

...and the output will be `class="type-photoset"`.